# Показать Preloader при ожидании запроса в более 500 мс

Tags: jquery, ajax

Стандартный запрос по клику

```
$("#load").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function (data) {
            $('#loading_box').show();
        },
        success: function (j) {
            $('#loading_box').hide();
            $('#content').html(j.html);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Думаю, в `beforeSend` нужно показывать индикатор загрузки, внутри `setTimeout`. 
Но что если наступит событие `success` с командой скрытия индикатора, а затем закончится `timeout` и индикатор покажется, когда уже не нужен?

Прелоадер нужно показывать при загрузке, дольше определённого времени и скрывать, когда пришёл ответ. Кроме того, нужно учитывать, что возможен повторный клик и запуск запроса, также он может быть не успешен. Очевидно что во всех этих случаях `timeout` должен очиститься и начинаться заново при последнем запросе.

Можете ли подсказать алгоритм или пример кода? Или, возможно, есть что то готовое для такого продвинутого вывода индикатора?

Comment: У ajax есть событие `done: function() {}`. Неважно вернёт ответ сервер или выйдет время, оно сработает по завершению запроса. Никакой `setTimeout` не нужен. А в beforeSend не индикатор загрузки, а лишь что-то вроде "пожалуйста подождите"

Comment: Для индикатора загрузки нужно в ответе от сервера указать заголовок `Content-Length` и его длину. Если вопрос в этом, именно в индикаторе загрузки, могу дать развёрнутый ответ. А в ajax есть есть такое событие как `complete: function() {}`. Срабатывает по завершению запроса

Comment: И ещё я не понял, почему `return false`. Вместо кнопки ссылка чтоли?

Comment: >И ещё я не понял, почему return false да ссылки всегда используем

Comment: Насчет Content-Length что это даст? Я имел ввиду свой кастомный индикатор типа gif картинки например

Comment: Но зачем использовать ссылку, если можно взять `button` или `input` с типом `submit` или `button`. Или вообще просто в ссылку убрать `href`

Comment: Про complete: function()  понимаю в ней можно скрыть индикатор. Но почему setTimeout не нужен? Ведь я говорю о том что нужно показать индикатор, не сразу в beforeSend а только если запрос продолжается более 500 мс. Это главное в задаче..

Comment: Посылаем запрос, если более пол секунды, показываем прелоадер, если ответ пришёл раньше заданного времени, то не показываем его. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Про html верстку мне кажется не так важно, да и в моем случае это ответственность верстальщика. Я просто навешиваю на id обработчик и все..

Comment: >Я правильно понял? Да Вы правильно описали логику задачи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function (data) {
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                gif.show();
            }, 500);
        },
        complete: function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            gif.hide();
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Даже не знаю для чего это нужно, доля секунды ничтожно мала, понимаю ещё секунды две. Тем не менее, устанавливаем `timer`, если запрос не успеет выполниться меньше, чем за это время, то будет показан прелоадер, в противном случае его не будет

Comment: Я бы поставил флаг, чтобы запрос не запускался, если не выполнился предыдущий

Comment: Можно поставить и более чем 500 мс. Главное логика.

Comment: Не запускался пока не выполнился предыдущий... Но если пользователь нажал на один фильтр, затем сразу на другой, то зачем ждать пока предыдущий сработает? Думаю тогда нужно что уже более новый выполнился.. Или наличие предыдущего запроса, может спутать логику текущему? Например сработает таймер от предыдущего запроса? Тогда нужно в beforeSend еще и очистить таймер от возможного предыдущего запроса?

Comment: @htclog81, вот тут точно не скажу. Переменная таймера переназначится. А при отсутсвии будет ошибка, хотя можно поставить `var timer`